# Typescript error trying to wrap a function inside another function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to wrap a function inside another function before passing it to a library to be run later. I'm getting all sorts of Typescript errors trying to use .apply() and spreading arguments.

The library requires me to pass an "options" object including a function called PromiseFn to it which will be called by the library with an arbitrary number of arguments.

I need to wrap the promiseFn in a new function which will run some code before and after calling the original promiseFn. The new function will be the one passed to the library. This is what I've tried.

```
let newOptions = options

if(options.promiseFn !== undefined){

    let newPromiseFn = async (...args: any[]) => {

        ... before code

        await options.promiseFn?.apply(this, ...args)

        ... before code

    }

    newOptions.promiseFn = newPromiseFn

}

const { data } = useAsync(newOptions)
```

The typescript error that I'm currently getting is...

**(parameter) args: any[]
Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 1 or more.ts(2556)**

It relates to the args in this line

```
await options.promiseFn?.apply(this, ...args)
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: What does `promiseFn` look like?

Comment: It can be any function passed to my middle layer but according to typescripts it looks like - (property) AsyncOptions<any>.promiseFn?: PromiseFn<any> | undefined

Comment: Ah, try removing the `...`, so `options.promiseFn?.apply(this, args)` ?

Comment: Unfortunately then I get - Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[props: AsyncProps<any>, controller: AbortController]'.
  Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2345)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, you just want to use something that can wrap your function.

I think you can use something like this :

```
type GetReturnType<original extends Function> = original extends (...x: any[]) => infer returnType ? returnType : never;
type GetArgumentsType<originalArguments> = originalArguments extends (...args: infer formatArguments) => any ? formatArguments : never[];

const myEncapsulatedFunction = async <T extends Function>(
    func: T,
    ...args: GetArgumentsType<T>
): Promise<GetReturnType<T>> => wrappingFunction(func, args)();
```

Then you can just use this wrapper like that:

```
function wrappingFunction<T extends any[]>(func: Function, args: T) {
  // Do some stuff here
  await func(...args)
  // Do some stuff here
}

// Then
function doStuff(arg: string) {
  console.log(arg)
}


myEncapsulatedFunction(doStuff, 'hello');
```