# Passing parameter type to the same function gives compiler error

Tags: typescript

I want to wrap a function with another call without having to write all of the definitions of the original function. In this case, the original method has over 30 overloads defined, and I don't really want to make sure mine and their definition stays up-to-date. Also, the return type is dependent on the parameters given, so I can't really make a shortcut in that regard.

```
// A function from a library with some overloads, note that the return type is dependent on the function arguments
declare function foo<TState, T>(
  state: TState,
  project: (state: any) => T): T;
declare function foo<TState1, TState2, T>(
  s1: TState1,
  s2: TState2,
  project: (s1: TState1, s2: TState2) => T): T;

// The function I want to make, uses the original with a minor change
function bar<T extends Parameters<typeof foo>>(...args: T) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(foo(...args));
             // ^^^^^^^ ts(2556): Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 0 or more.
  }));
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEFQMwVwOwMYBcCWB7O0BOaC2oBDUAGxQCMsCsBPAGlAGcYAHZtBgU1CQAsUHQPAgKQYBaKKDQA3DlmJoCAEwEB3HnK68uWDkhhZMSasy79QSjqbiW4SKUY2hmVArj1yGAKEsJiVLlhEVAxoNDQAHgAVAGUkAiQOAEZ6KIA+AAovUEYkgC5QWPjElOznHAArDmQCjIZijgKCOGoASlAAXjTC1oKogG4fav9daHhkdEwocOi4hOTUucSAJlTMsoZ8wqWFjeW+ndWy5krqpFrNg4aUxn3thuX2rp6+wa8QQqcgidCASVBVM17KJQLgCABrDj0GCcERONBYFAAcxQcAIxABKF4hFBqIRoAQQjgSI4Xm+IUwZCoGQAdHSqEiGAUAAqudyJLAMCLGUwSMJoNLtADeZV0+kMoDgHFUoGZOFw-A4GV0DDQxFknW6nCQURQ7jQMCQGQyT26IpyORVatkGWmaFp9KwjNarUGOQAvi7Bu6vL6PlEOPVQFivAgxPZ6vMkp1QObJW5GqAAOSRkpJ2hed2DMNwIOpjjLGNxlBKApHH2h8OgFUwYj2DqgKlYOrXej51agOo3BiPTW5Glo9ygADUtxpJdd7zAm1AADJboRRvBwWhVJgALRangG4hKRtcBgJwgCfPR5p79tT6uB2vnWXyxURZdwVdwbqbxjb2t7shcOV4R96kRYk0i8IA) link updated to factor in the solution of [willis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67133772/2158015).

The error doesn't make too much sense for me since `args: T extends [s1: unknown, s2: unknown, project: (s1: unknown, s2: unknown) => unknown]` which is thus guaranteed to have exactly 3 arguments.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

---

**Expanded example**

I'm writing some generic code so I have less ngrx boilerplate code. This a part of what I want to achieve:

```
export abstract class FeatureQuery {
  public constructor(protected store: Store<any>) {}

  /* other useful methods */

  protected selectFrom<T extends Parameters<typeof createSelector>(...args: T) {
    return this.store.select(createSelector(...args));
  }
}
```

So I just want to wrap `createSelector` with `this.store.select` since in this context, we already know the store and don't need to wrap it anymore in any derived-class keeping the code more succinct.

**Related questions**

- [Typescript error trying to wrap a function inside another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64809864/typescript-error-trying-to-wrap-a-function-inside-another-function)

  - Doesn't work since this assumes a fixed return type independent of the parameters which is not the case
- [How to setup the types for functions that wraps given functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64850655/how-to-setup-the-types-for-functions-that-wraps-given-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

  - Same issue as above

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Changing the call to `foo` to use `.apply` (e. g. `return foo.apply(this, args).getUTCDate();`) works just fine.

Comment: And sure enough, it is - see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4130

Answer (score 0):

I've created an issue on the TypeScript Github: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43731

Their answer:

> Parameters is based on type inferrence in conditional types, and type inferrence in conditional types does not support overloading: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types
>
> This is a known design limitation.

So to answer: no, what I was trying to do is not possible.